# Bicep create random string with length of x

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

Trying to create a storage account and I run into problems that StorageAccountAlredyTaken.

What is best practice of doing this?

```
// getting paramerts from json file
param storageName string

//pseudo code
1. get length of storageName
2. add random string behind "storageName" and add a random length of x-characters so that the storage name get 24 characters
```

ex
storageName = rg-supercode-dev-westeurope-(storageName has the total of 24 characters length)

Comment: You can have a look at this doc around naming convention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/naming-and-tagging.

Comment: Look at the `uniqueString` function.

Comment: Here's some documentation on uniqueString with an example that includes unique storage account name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#uniquestring

Answer (score 1):

In bicep you can use a combination of uniqueString, some supplied seed string and substring to synthesize a unique string of maximum length

```
param fooseed string

param storageAccountName string = substring('${fooseed}sa${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}', 0, 24)
param servicePlanName    string = substring('${fooseed}plan${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}', 0, 24)
```

notice in above I embed `sa` to denote its a storageAccount, ditto using `plan`

which is executed using

```
az deployment group create \
  --template-file main.bicep \
  --parameters fooseed=$fooseed
```

Comment: `take` might be better option than 'substring'. Using substring will err if total length is less than 24 chars.